# Copy JSON data from Snowflake into S3

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, file-copying

I am trying to COPY data (Variant data type - JSON) from Snowflake to S3. I am using below command:

```
copy into @STG_SF_S3_DEV_JJC/sample_file1.json
from (select distinct RECORD_CONTENT from MYTABLE where LOAD_DT_TS >= '2022-02-09 00:00:00')
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON,COMPRESSION = NONE)
SINGLE=true
header=true
OVERWRITE = TRUE;
```

The data is getting copied. I am using STORAGE_INTEGRATION process & creating STAGE table.
My question is:

> 1. For above query, I am getting 23 rows and I want to load these 23 rows as 23 separate files (JSON files) in S3. How to achieve this?
> 2. Each record has different LOAD_DT_TS and so for each 23 files, I need to give different names. I mean, the file name should end with LOAD_DT_TS. How to achieve this?
> 3. **MYTABLE** in above query (COPY command), I have 4 columns. Is there any possible way to load all the 4 columns into a single JSON file?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below (it covers point #1 and 2).

```
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select * from test_pivot;
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| COMPANY | BU        | EVAL_DESC | MEMBER_ID |
|---------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
| C1      | FINANCIAL | L1        | ID1       |
| C1      | FINANCIAL | L2        | ID2       |
| C1      | FINANCIAL | L3        | ID3       |
| C1      | HR        | L1        | ID4       |
| C1      | HR        | L2        | ID5       |
| C2      | FINANCIAL | L1        | ID6       |
| C2      | BUSINESS  | L1        | ID7       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
7 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.187s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>list @test_row_stage;
+------+------+-----+---------------+
| name | size | md5 | last_modified |
|------+------+-----+---------------|
+------+------+-----+---------------+
0 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.177s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
                                     DECLARE
                                       company varchar2(30);
                                       BU varchar2(30);
                                       eval_desc varchar2(30);
                                       member_id varchar2(30);
                                       file_name varchar2(30);
                                       c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test_pivot;
                                     BEGIN
                                      // OPEN c1;
                                       for record in c1 do
                                       company:=record.company;
                                       BU:=record.BU;
                                       eval_desc:=record.eval_desc;
                                       member_id:=record.member_id;
                                       file_name:='load'||'_'||member_id||'.csv';
                                       create or replace temporary table temp_test_pvt(company varchar2(30),BU varchar2
                                     (30),eval_desc varchar2(30),member_id varchar2(30));
                                       insert into temp_test_pvt values (:company,:bu,:eval_desc,:member_id);
                                       execute immediate 'copy into @test_row_stage/'||:file_name||' from (select * fro
                                     m temp_test_pvt) overwrite=false';
                                       end for;
                                       RETURN 0;
                                     END;
                                     $$
                                     ;
+-----------------+
| anonymous block |
|-----------------|
|               0 |
+-----------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 9.803s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>list @test_row_stage;
+------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| name                                     | size | md5                              | last_modified                 |
|------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------|
| test_row_stage/load_ID1.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | df314a0d95a771d5d81fa9b1cfb3a28e | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:42 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID2.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | 6be39868046f583b1c63d616faa9e7f6 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:43 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID3.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | ecf9dbcb4e45fa29d6bcfe268c6ccae3 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:44 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID4.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | 0fd3ff7e0a453e04be3aca22147a7d32 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:45 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID5.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | c77985f8312a540816d82b4bf4ec5249 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:46 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID6.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | c9e9d6fd613a8bdb76413dd3e9464cc4 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:47 GMT |
| test_row_stage/load_ID7.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 | 4e4b999ed56059b44ee6bd15f28cafb8 | Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:47:48 GMT |
+------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
7 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.176s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select $1,$2,$3,$4 from @test_row_stage/load_ID1.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz;
+----+-----------+----+-----+
| $1 | $2        | $3 | $4  |
|----+-----------+----+-----|
| C1 | FINANCIAL | L1 | ID1 |
+----+-----------+----+-----+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.429s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select $1,$2,$3,$4 from @test_row_stage/load_ID2.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz;
+----+-----------+----+-----+
| $1 | $2        | $3 | $4  |
|----+-----------+----+-----|
| C1 | FINANCIAL | L2 | ID2 |
+----+-----------+----+-----+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.374s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select $1,$2,$3,$4 from @test_row_stage/load_ID3.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz;
+----+-----------+----+-----+
| $1 | $2        | $3 | $4  |
|----+-----------+----+-----|
| C1 | FINANCIAL | L3 | ID3 |
+----+-----------+----+-----+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.506s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select $1,$2,$3,$4 from @test_row_stage/load_ID4.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz;
+----+----+----+-----+
| $1 | $2 | $3 | $4  |
|----+----+----+-----|
| C1 | HR | L1 | ID4 |
+----+----+----+-----+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.281s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>
```

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
$$
 DECLARE
    load_dt_tss timestamp;
 file_name varchar2(30);
 c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= '2022-02-09 00:00:00';
 BEGIN
      for record in c1 do
          load_dt_tss:=record.LOAD_DT_TS;
          file_name:=load_dt_tss||'.csv';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'copy into @mystage/'||:file_name|| 
            'from (select col1 from mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= ''2022-02-09 00:00:00'')
            FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON,COMPRESSION = NONE)
            overwrite=FALSE';
          end for;
      RETURN 0;
 END;$$ ;

Comment: Hi @Pankaj - I just modified the query given by you.. But i am getting error as 
"Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 10 at position 10 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 62 unexpected '03'."
can you please help me in this?

Comment: Its error due to placement of quotes. Please try this (line# 10) -         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'copy into @mystage/'||:file_name|| 'from (select col1 from mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= '''|| '''2022-02-09 00:00:00'''|| ') FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON,COMPRESSION = NONE) overwrite=FALSE';

Comment: hi @Pankaj -- No luck still.
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 10 at position 10 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 62 unexpected '03'. parse error line 2 at position 70 near '<EOF>'. I tried adding quotes also.. still didnt work.. I understand, that the COPY command is causing issue. But not able to figure out.

Comment: Why are you doing a query when copying into stage? As per your requirements you needed to load 1 row at a time per file. The program that I gave earlier did that using a intermediate temporary table that holds just one record per iteration and then loads same as a file into stage and then the next record and so forth. If you need to use a condition perhaps to load all records into a stage file then do not use a cursor. Please check what is needed. I will also look into just the query part for loading and try to share fix for same

Comment: I have a table that is loaded every 1hr for a period of time. That table has 2 columns (variant data type & load_dt_ts). Every EOD, i want these data to be copied into S3 as part of backup. So I will take backup of records that has loaded only for today & so i am using this DATE filter in cursor. Also since it is a JSON type data, I wanted to load each data (one full set array) as one single file. I wanted to backup the data and the LOAD_DT_TS should be the file name. This helps to identify which data came at what time, minutes & seconds. That's why i modified ur query like this.

Comment: I have provided new query with quotes placement, please try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for input a predicate value with quotes placement -

```
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
                                     DECLARE
                                      load_dt_tss timestamp;
                                      file_name varchar2(30);
                                     BEGIN
                                      file_name:='somefile'||'.csv';
                                      execute immediate 'copy into @test_row_stage/'||:file_name||' from (select LOAD_D
                                     T_TS from TEST_TS where LOAD_DT_TS >=' || '''2022-02-09 00:00:00''' || ')' || ' FI
                                     LE_FORMAT = (TYPE=CSV,COMPRESSION = NONE) overwrite=FALSE';
                                      RETURN 0;
                                     END;
                                     $$
                                     ;
+-----------------+
| anonymous block |
|-----------------|
|               0 |
+-----------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.584s
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj. But this also didn't work and throwing error. I am working on to fix this. Some where in the COPY command only this error is generated.

Comment: Please carefully check on placement of quotes. If you share what you are running and error being received, I can try to check on that.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
$$
 DECLARE
  load_dt_tss timestamp;
  file_name varchar2(30);
 BEGIN
  file_name:='somefile'||'.csv';
  execute immediate 
   'copy into @STG_SF_S3_DEV_JJC/'||:file_name||
   'from (select distinct record_content from AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER.T_PO_STG where LOAD_DT_TS >=' || '''2022-02-09 00:00:00''' || ')' || ' 
   FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=CSV,COMPRESSION = NONE) overwrite=FALSE';
  RETURN 0;
 END;
$$ ;

**Error:** Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 7 at position 2 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 46 unexpected '('.

Comment: Added the exact query & error here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552614/copy-variant-into-s3-from-snowflake
Had issue in pasting here. So created new ticket.

Answer (score 0):

SINGLE=true - This option send the full SQL output to single file, if you remove this it will send the output to separate files.