# COPY Variant into S3 from Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Source Data]

Attached picture is my source data in a Snowflake table. I need to copy this into S3 as 2 individual files.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
    DECLARE
        load_dt_tss timestamp;
        file_name varchar2(30);
        c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_CONTENT, LOAD_DT_TS FROM mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= '2022-02-09 00:00:00';
    BEGIN
        for record in c1 do
            load_dt_tss:=RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS;
            file_name:=load_dt_tss||'.csv'; 
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'copy into @STG_SF_S3/'||:file_name|| 'from (select record_content from mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= ''2022-02-09 00:00:00'') FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON,COMPRESSION = NONE) single = FALSE overwrite=FALSE';
        end for;
        RETURN 0;
    END;
$$ ;
```

Above given is the Query I'm using. When running this query, I get **Error** as:
**"Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 10 at position 3 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 40 unexpected '21' ".**

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE database AAP_LDS_DEV_DB;
create schema AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER;
create table AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER.T_PO_STG(RECORD_CONTENT variant, LOAD_DT_TS timestamp_ntz );

insert into AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER.T_PO_STG (SELECT parse_json(column1), to_timestamp(column2) from values
    ('{"blar":"blar1"}','2022-02-10'),
    ('{"blar":"blar2"}','2022-02-11')
 );
 


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
   DECLARE
        sql text;
        file_name text;
        c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_CONTENT, LOAD_DT_TS FROM AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER.T_PO_STG where LOAD_DT_TS >= '2022-02-09 00:00:00';
    BEGIN
        for record in c1 do
            file_name := to_char(RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS, 'yyyymmdd_hhmmss') || '.csv'; 
            sql := 'copy into @STG_SF_S3_DEV_JJC/' || :file_name || ' from (select record_content from AAP_LDS_DEV_DB.PURCHASE_ORDER.T_PO_STG where LOAD_DT_TS = ''' || RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS || ''') FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON,COMPRESSION = NONE) single = FALSE overwrite=FALSE';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql; 
        end for;
        RETURN 0;
    END;
$$ ;
```

Comment: HI @Simeon 
It didn't work. Error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 9 at position 73 unexpected 'from'.

Comment: Hi @Simeon. Your query worked, but had a to make a small change. I just replaced the $$ before the FROM and replaced that with single quote. So, that issue was fixed. That TO_CHAR conversion was the one I was missing and causing all this issue.

Now, the files are generated as expected. but the issue is, each files are having all the data written in it. As per the source table attached, here i should get 2 files generated with one data in each file. But now each files has 2 data in it. So working around to fix that.

Comment: I just used the SELECT sql you provided, assume you were doing what you wanted there. I have pivoted it, so now the select is just a equality test, against the per row timestamp, which now that it's in the row, I didn't need to other escaping, albeit, I could have used a double single quote to embedded it in the string.

Comment: Thanks @Simeon. The **TO_CHAR** conversion was giving different TIME compared to the original TIME. So I modified it to use **file_name := 'PO'||'_'||to_date(RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS)||'_'||TO_TIME(RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS)||'.json';**

Another change was I did **"DECLARE records variant"** and added **"records := RECORD.record_content;  create or replace temporary table temp_test_pvt(records variant);   insert into temp_test_pvt select parse_json(:records) ;"**  before **"sql:= "**.

Now I got what i wanted. I have pasted final query above. Thanks again ur query that helped me find out what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
$$
    DECLARE
        file_name varchar2(30);
        records variant;
        c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_CONTENT, LOAD_DT_TS FROM mytable where LOAD_DT_TS >= '2022-02-09 00:00:00';
    BEGIN
        for record in c1 do
            file_name := 'PO'||'_'||to_date(RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS)||'_'||TO_TIME(RECORD.LOAD_DT_TS)||'.json';
            records := RECORD.record_content;
            create or replace temporary table temp_test_pvt(records variant);
              insert into temp_test_pvt select parse_json(:records) ;
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'copy into @STG_SF_S3/' || :file_name ||
            ' from (select distinct records from temp_test_pvt)
            FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=JSON, COMPRESSION = NONE) single = true overwrite=FALSE detailed_output = TRUE ';
        end for;
        RETURN 0;
    END;
$$ ;
```

This is my final query. With this I am able to COPY one record as one file from Snowflake table into S3.