# Use column values as filenames when COPYing into a stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an out-of-the-box method for Snowflake to use values from a column as a filename when using `COPY INTO @mystage`? The goal is to copy X number of files into an s3 stage (essentially PARTITION BY column1), but straight to the stage, not creating subfolders. X would be the number of distinct values in a column.

This can obviously be done manually:

`copy into @mystage/mycustomfilename`

However, the better option would be something like this:

`copy into @mystage/$column1`

Is there a version of this that Snowflake supports?

As mentioned above, the `PARTITION BY` setting parses data into subfolders and the subfolders are named using the values in the specified column, but Snowflake still uses a generic filename within each subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created structure -

```
create temporary table temp_tab_split_members(seq_id number, member_id number, name varchar2(30));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| status                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| Table TEMP_TAB_SPLIT_MEMBERS successfully created. |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Fake data -

```
insert into temp_tab_split_members
with cte as
(select seq4(),(trim(mod(seq4(),4))+1)::integer,'my name-'||seq4() from table(generator(rowcount=>12)))
select * from cte;
+-------------------------+
| number of rows inserted |
|-------------------------|
|                      12 |
+-------------------------+
```

Checking data format -

```
select * from TEMP_TAB_SPLIT_MEMBERS order by member_id;
+--------+-----------+------------+
| SEQ_ID | MEMBER_ID | NAME       |
|--------+-----------+------------|
|      0 |         1 | my name-0  |
|      4 |         1 | my name-4  |
|      8 |         1 | my name-8  |
|      1 |         2 | my name-1  |
|      5 |         2 | my name-5  |
|      9 |         2 | my name-9  |
|      2 |         3 | my name-2  |
|      6 |         3 | my name-6  |
|     10 |         3 | my name-10 |
|      3 |         4 | my name-3  |
|      7 |         4 | my name-7  |
|     11 |         4 | my name-11 |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Checked stage is empty

```
list @test_row_stage;
+------+------+-----+---------------+
| name | size | md5 | last_modified |
|------+------+-----+---------------|
+------+------+-----+---------------+
```

## Main procedure to generate files

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  company varchar2(30);
  BU varchar2(30);
  eval_desc varchar2(30);
  member_id varchar2(30);
  file_name varchar2(30);
  c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct member_id FROM temp_tab_split_members;
BEGIN
  for record in c1 do
  member_id:=record.member_id;
  file_name:='load'||'_'||member_id||'.csv';
  execute immediate 'copy into @test_row_stage/'||:file_name||' from 
  (select * from temp_tab_split_members where member_id='||:member_id||') overwrite=false';
  end for;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$
;
+-----------------+
| anonymous block |
|-----------------|
|               0 |
+-----------------+
```

Check stage contents after procedure execution

```
list @test_row_stage; -- output truncated columnwise
+----------------------------------------+------+
| name                                   | size |
|----------------------------------------+------+
| test_row_stage/load_1.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 |
| test_row_stage/load_2.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 |
| test_row_stage/load_3.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 |
| test_row_stage/load_4.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz |   48 |
```

File contents cross-check

```
select $1,$2,$3 from @test_row_stage/load_1.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz union
select $1,$2,$3 from @test_row_stage/load_2.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz union
select $1,$2,$3 from @test_row_stage/load_3.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz union
select $1,$2,$3 from @test_row_stage/load_4.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz;
+----+----+------------+
| $1 | $2 | $3         |
|----+----+------------|
| 0  | 1  | my name-0  |
| 4  | 1  | my name-4  |
| 8  | 1  | my name-8  |
| 1  | 2  | my name-1  |
| 5  | 2  | my name-5  |
| 9  | 2  | my name-9  |
| 2  | 3  | my name-2  |
| 6  | 3  | my name-6  |
| 10 | 3  | my name-10 |
| 3  | 4  | my name-3  |
| 7  | 4  | my name-7  |
| 11 | 4  | my name-11 |
+----+----+------------+
```

Comment: this is PERFECT. thank you so much! great flexibility with the cursor select distinct as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB for this as I understand, but you can write custom code and fetch values and use them to name files and copy them to stage/s3.
Please refer below for something similar -

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  company varchar2(30);
  BU varchar2(30);
  eval_desc varchar2(30);
  member_id varchar2(30);
  file_name varchar2(30);
  c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test_pivot;
BEGIN
  for record in c1 do
  company:=record.company;
  BU:=record.BU;
  eval_desc:=record.eval_desc;
  member_id:=record.member_id;
  file_name:='load'||'_'||member_id||'.csv';
  create or replace temporary table temp_test_pvt(company varchar2(30),BU varchar2(30),eval_desc varchar2(30),member_id varchar2(30));
  insert into temp_test_pvt values (:company,:bu,:eval_desc,:member_id);
  execute immediate 'copy into @test_row_stage/'||:file_name||' from (select * from temp_test_pvt) overwrite=false';
  end for;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$
;
```

Also, refer a similar post here -
[Copy JSON data from Snowflake into S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512356/copy-json-data-from-snowflake-into-s3/71516173#71516173)

Comment: interesting, will give this a try. thanks!

Comment: this is close to the answer, but this script writes each row as a new file. is there a way to group the results to 1 file by the specified column?

in this case the `file_name` is split by `member_id`. if `member_id` has 10 rows per 1 ID, this will write 10 files per value.