# How to copy records from into files for each division in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

HI There i am very new to snowflake and need your help in guiding me a solution.

I have a requirement to fetch data from snowflake table and copy into azure storage account,
I have one Division table and one Main table,
I need to fetch data from Main table for each division and write  data into file, the file name should be having PrefixName as filename for each division data file.

Join Condition  division.FIID= main.DIVISION_OWNER_NM

Division Table

| DivisionName | DivisionNumber | FIID | Prefix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Denver | 06 | DENV | DV06 |
| Dallas | 04 | DALL | DV04 |
| Houston | 29 | HOUS | DV29 |
| Harrisburg | 26 | HARR | DV26 |

Main Table:

| TERMINAL_ID | DIVISION_OWNER_NM | MESSAGE_TYPE_CD | TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | HOUS | 0100 | 00 |
| 456789 | HOUS | 0200 | 00 |
| 234789 | DENV | 0500 | 00 |
| 555789 | HARR | 0200 | 00 |
| 555449 | DENV | 0300 | 00 |

Comment: There are some blogs that cover how to store query results or unload data from Snowflake to Azure blobs - here’s one:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6508/copy-data-from-and-to-snowflake-with-azure-data-factory/

Comment: If your question is more about how to construct your SQL query, please advise.

Comment: In case you are only looking to store table rows as file names in snowflake stage (pointing to azure storage) you may refer to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654138/use-column-values-as-filenames-when-copying-into-a-stage/71669499#71669499). This one is for AWS S3 though but idea is same as copy is to snowflake stage and it can be pointing to any supported cloud vendor.

Comment: if you want the help on to find an approach to copy data from snowflake to azure this should be able to do using capabilities of the ETL tool currently in use (ADF, Airflow). Are there any such tools exists?

Comment: Thank you Jim, Pankaj, sav you inputs are really helpful

Answer (score 0):

besides the helpful links in the comments maybe a code sample, which is using the tables you provided.
I would solve it with a procedure:

```
--Create Table Division
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.DIVISION AS
SELECT 'Denver' AS DivisionName, '06' AS DivisionNumber, 'DENV' AS FIID, 'DV06' AS Prefix
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dallas' AS DivisionName, '04' AS DivisionNumber, 'DALL' AS FIID, 'DV04' AS Prefix
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Houston' AS DivisionName, '29' AS DivisionNumber, 'HOUS' AS FIID, 'DV29' AS Prefix
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Harrisburg' AS DivisionName, '26' AS DivisionNumber, 'HARR' AS FIID, 'DV26' AS Prefix;

--Create Table Main
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.MAIN AS
SELECT 123456 AS Terminal_ID, 'HOUS' AS DIVISION_OWNER_NM, '0100' AS MESSAGE_TYPE_CD, '00' AS TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT 456789 AS Terminal_ID, 'HOUS' AS DIVISION_OWNER_NM, '0200' AS MESSAGE_TYPE_CD, '00' AS TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT 234789 AS Terminal_ID, 'DENV' AS DIVISION_OWNER_NM, '0500' AS MESSAGE_TYPE_CD, '00' AS TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT 555789 AS Terminal_ID, 'HARR' AS DIVISION_OWNER_NM, '0200' AS MESSAGE_TYPE_CD, '00' AS TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
UNION ALL
SELECT 555449 AS Terminal_ID, 'DENV' AS DIVISION_OWNER_NM, '0300' AS MESSAGE_TYPE_CD, '00' AS TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD;

--Create Test-Stage
CREATE STAGE TEST.EXPORT
storage_integration = AZURE_INT
url = 'azure://tstblob.blob.core.windows.net/snfdemo/';


--Create Stage
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST.SP_LOAD_TO_AZURE()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    //get FIID and PREFIX fields from Division table and store them into divisions_res variable
    var get_divisions_sql = `SELECT DISTINCT FIID, PREFIX FROM TEST.DIVISION;`;
    var get_divisions     = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:get_divisions_sql});
    var divisions_res = get_divisions.execute();
    
    //loop over resultset and execute COPY INTO jobs, that will add the prefix to the files
    //and filters the MAIN table by the division
    while(divisions_res.next()){
        division = divisions_res.getColumnValue(1);
        prefix = divisions_res.getColumnValue(2);
        
        copy_into_azure_sql = `COPY INTO @TEST.EXPORT/` + prefix + ` FROM
            (SELECT 
                Terminal_ID,
                DIVISION_OWNER_NM,
                MESSAGE_TYPE_CD,
                TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
             FROM TEST.MAIN
             WHERE DIVISION_OWNER_NM = '` + division + `')`;
        var copy_into_azure     = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:copy_into_azure_sql});
        copy_into_azure.execute();
    }
    
    return "Success";
$$
;

CALL TEST.SP_LOAD_TO_AZURE();
```

Result would look like this:
[image]

If you don't want the "0_0_0" or the compression you would need to make adjustments to the [copy options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#copy-options-copyoptions).
Hope this helps!
Best regards,

TK